# Calendar API incremental sync 'list' request doesn't give correct response on recurring event instance first update/cancel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, push-notification, google-calendar-api

Calendar API incremental sync 'list' request doesn't give correct response on recurring event instance first update/cancel

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a recurring event in Google Calendar
2. Perform initial full sync and grab syncToken value
3. Update event title for any instance of this recurring event ('This event' option) or cancel that instance
4. Execute event list request and send syncToken value (query delta)

Actual result:

- Response contains both recurring event and single instance that has been updated/canceled.

  When it's updated, "UpdatedRaw" and "ETag" values are the same for both recurring and instance events.

Expected result:

- Response does not contain recurring event (as conceptually it hasn't been updated) and only a single instance is included.

  This way API consumers are able to identify what's actually been updated (recurring event or individual instance)

Note:

- It behaves as expected if the same action is applied to the instance which is already an exception (updated earlier).